# Updating current timestamp of multiple tables through single trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have 2 tables created :- Table Banks and Branch. Both the tables have column last_updated(which means when was the record last updated.) I have created after update trigger for each row on both the tables. The trigger and trigger function looks like below :-

```
create trigger banks_upd_trg
after update of phone_no
on Banks
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE bankdetails_upd();

create trigger branch_upd_trg
after update of email_address
on Branch
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE bankdetails_upd();


create or replace FUNCTION bankdetails_upd()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

BEGIN 

EXECUTE format('update %I.%I SET last_updated=current_timestamp where id=new.id',TG_SHEMA_NAME,TG_TABLE_NAME)

RETURN NEW;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

The trigger is getting executed successfully but isn't working at the time of updating phone_no and email_address column in Banks and Branch table respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for dynamic SQL or an `UPDATE` statement.

Use a `before` trigger and assign the value to the `NEW` record.

```
create or replace FUNCTION bankdetails_upd()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

BEGIN 
  new.last_updated := current_timestamp; 
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
create trigger banks_upd_trg
BEFORE update of phone_no
on Banks
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE bankdetails_upd();

create trigger branch_upd_trg
BEFORE update of email_address
on Branch
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE bankdetails_upd();
```